# Selecting element in external SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, xmlhttprequest, es6-promise

I'm trying to select and modify specific parts of an SVG via D3.js. The SVG is external. I don't know whether to import the SVG via  tags or using d3.xml. Neither is working for me.

I managed to get the SVG in the HTML via  tags but I still can't select any of the elements within the SVG using d3.

I also do not know if best practice is to use use  tags or d3.xml

https://jsfiddle.net/67fvhwc0/

```
d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Baseball_diamond_clean.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
  if (error) throw error;
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
});

var base = d3.select('#rect2801');
console.log(base);
base.attr("fill", "red");
```

Comment: <object> tags are the ones i'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple error here: you're using D3 v5, not v4. Because of that, you have to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (instead of XMLHttpRequest in v4).

Therefore, it should be:

```
d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Baseball_diamond_clean.svg")
    .then(function(xml) {
        document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
    });
```

Also, move everything that depends on the data to inside `Promise.prototype.then()`, or to the adequate function. So:

```
d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Baseball_diamond_clean.svg")
    .then(function(xml) {
        document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
        var base = d3.select('#rect2801');
        console.log(base);
    });
```

To read more about the changes in D3 v5: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Here is your working code:

```js
d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Baseball_diamond_clean.svg").then(function(xml) {
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
  var base = d3.select('#rect2801');
  base.style("fill", "red")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: We cannot `console.log` D3 selections in the stack snippet, it freezes. Instead of that, I'm turning the base red.

PPS: Don't use `<object>`. You'll find out that's complicated using D3 selectors on that SVG.